# How can I localize showDatePicker on a single-locale app?

Tags: localization, flutter

I have an app intended for just one locale that is not English, so it includes hardcoded strings in Text objects. I'm attempting to localize showDatePicker()

If I try to pass `localizationsDelegates: [GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate]` to the MaterialApp I get an exception.

And if I try to pass `locale: const Locale("es")` to showDatePicker without passing `localizationDelegates` to `MaterialApp`, I get an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved it.

Pass these arguments to the `materialApp`:

```dart
localizationsDelegates: const [
  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate, // ONLY if it's a RTL language
],
supportedLocales: const [
  Locale('fr', 'FR'), // include country code too
],
```

And since the locale is already defined, it's not necessary to pass it to `showDatePicker`.

Comment: I get an error: Unsupported operation: Cannot set value in unmodifiable Map

Comment: Try adding const to the lists, I'll update the answer